# ¿Cómo acceder a otro sitio de Sharepoint mediante un workflow en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint

Necesito acceder a un sitio de `SharePoint` (SITIO B) desde un workflow alojado en una biblioteca de otro sitio de `SharePoint` (SITIO A). Sé que directamente no es posible desde el `SharePoint` designer por lo que estoy haciendo desde un workflow creado en `Visual Studio 2015`. He logrado lo que quiero hacer mediante un servicio web, pero me gustaría saber si se puede hacer directamente desde un workflow.

He visto que se pueden crear actividades personalizadas donde puedo colocar el código para ejecutarlo, pero para esto necesito modificar partes del servidor y en el entorno que tengo eso no es posible.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Finalmente tuve que hacer uso del web service mediante una invocación del servicio dese un workflow alojado en el sitio creado en SPD, pues como comentan no es posible crear el flujo en `Visual Studio` sin modificar los ensamblados del sistema ya que se necesitan para que el flujo los reconozca como "White List".

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento, puedes actualizar la pregunta? En caso de que tengas mas inquietudes, intenta formular la pregunta con mayor información y generarla en el sitio de [SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hola. Si no puedes realizar instalaciones en el servidor, no vas a poder usar un flujo de trabajo de Visual Studio.